# Laravel 4 - username in URL changes to {Username} after pressing submit

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and am stuck on a syntax issue. I'm trying to make a view that will enable an admin to change the password of a user but when I click submit the page refreshes and the URL has replaced the username (ex: public/users/alex/edit to  public/users/{username}/edit). If anyone could explain why this isn't working it'd be greatly appreciated! I made something similar where the users can change their own password and that one seems to be working fine. My only guess is that I'm not carrying over the $username properly but I haven't a clue of how else to do it. Thank y'all so much! Any bit of info helps!

Here is the UserController for the view:

```
public function getEdit ($username) {   
        $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();
        return View::make('users.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function postEdit($username){

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                'password'          => 'required|min:6',
                'password_again'    => 'required|same:password'
            )
        );

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::route('user-edit')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->with('username', $username);
        } else {
            /*Change password*/
            $user           = User::whereUsername($username)->first();
            $password       = Input::get('password');
            $user->password = Hash::make($password); 
            /*password is the field $password is the variable that will be used in the password field*/

            if($user->save()){
                return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'The password has been changed.');
            }
        }
        return Redirect::route('account-change-password')
            ->with('global', 'The password could not be changed.');
    }
```

the Route:

```
/*ADMIN - edit users (GET)*/
    Route::get('users/{username}/edit', array(
        'as'    => 'user-edit',
        'uses'  => 'UserController@getEdit'
    ));

/*ADMIN - edit users (POST)*/
                Route::post('users/{username}/edit', array(
                    'as'    => 'user-edit-post',
                    'uses'  => 'UserController@postEdit'
                ));
```

and the View/Blade:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
    <form action="{{ URL::route('user-edit-post') }}" method="post">

        <div class="field">
            New password: <input type="password" name="password">

            @if($errors->has('password'))
                {{$errors->first('password')}}
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            New password again: <input type="password" name="password_again">

            @if($errors->has('password_again'))
                {{$errors->first('password_again')}}
            @endif
        </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Change Password">
        {{ Form::token() }}
    </form>
@stop
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem like you pass the username anywhere inside your form.  Have you tried using `{{ Form::open(...) }}` and `{{ Form::close() }}` (see http://laravel.com/docs/html)?  Those functions will handle parameter passing for you and include hidden variables if necessary.

Good luck!

Michal

Comment: Oh! Okay, I did not know that using {{Form::open}} would do all that! I will try it right now, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten to try it out. A friend tried to "help me" and ended up making such a mess I had to start from scratch lol. But I will be sure to keep this in mind.